# JQuery changing tooltip message on hover, depending on divs state

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip

I have a left menu in an Asp.Net web page. When clicking on the arrow image, the menu hiddens/shows up. And changes the arrow image(left and right ways of arrows). As follows:

html:

```
<div id="needle">
   <div id="arrowDiv"> 
     <img id="imgArrows" src="../Style/images/arrow-back.png" />
  </div>
</div>

 <div id="leftmenu">
    //..
 </div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#needle").click(function () {
 if ($('#leftmenu').is(':hidden')) {
$('#leftmenu').show();
$("#imgArrows").attr("src", "../Style/images/arrow-back.png");

} else {
$('#leftmenu').hide();
$("#imgArrows").attr("src", "../Style/images/arrow-forward.png");

}
});
});
```

I want to add a simple tooltip, which when client hovers on the , a tooltip message to appear and write "Hide" or "Show" as a message. (depending on if the div is closed tooltip message will be "Show", if open; then the message will be "Hide" on image hover)

So far I have wrote this. Not working. Could you help me, please?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#needle").click(function () {
 if ($('#leftmenu').is(':hidden')) {
$('#leftmenu').show();
$("#imgArrows").attr("src", "../Style/images/arrow-back.png");
 $("#imgArrows").attr('title', 'Hide');
} else {
$('#leftmenu').hide();
$("#imgArrows").attr("src", "../Style/images/arrow-forward.png");
 $("#imgArrows").attr('title', 'Show');
}
 $('#imgArrows').hover(function () {
 $('#imgArrows').tooltip();
 });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function in which you attached **hover** event is inside of **click** event.
So just move it outside of the click event and it should work. Also, as I can see you are using jQuery UI, so don't forget to add reference to that library too.

In your html code posted you have one extra closing div.

Here is HTML:

```
<div id="needle">
 <div id="arrowDiv"> 
 <img id="imgArrows" src="../Style/images/arrow-back.png" /></div>
 </div>
<div id="leftmenu">
//..
</div>
```

and js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#needle").click(function () {
      if($('#leftmenu').is(':hidden')) {
         $('#leftmenu').show();
         $("#imgArrows").attr("src", "../Style/images/arrow-back.png");
         $("#imgArrows").attr('title', 'Hide');
   } else {
         $('#leftmenu').hide();
         $("#imgArrows").attr("src", "../Style/images/arrow-forward.png");
         $("#imgArrows").attr('title', 'Show');
  }
});

   $('#imgArrows').hover(function () {
      alert('inside');
   },function(){
      alert('outside')
   });
});
```

**EDIT:** Actually you can use callback function. This works like whenever user hover mouse over image it says "inside", and when mouse is outside (callback func.) it says "outside". Hope it is clear.

**SECOND EDIT**. If you want to track state of if "left-menu" is open or closed you could introduce another variable like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

   var isHidden = false;

   $("#needle").click(function () {
      if($('#leftmenu').is(':hidden')) {
         $('#leftmenu').show();
         $("#imgArrows").attr("src", "../Style/images/arrow-back.png");
         $("#imgArrows").attr('title', 'Hide');
         isHidden = true; /*set it to true*/
   } else {
         $('#leftmenu').hide();
         $("#imgArrows").attr("src", "../Style/images/arrow-forward.png");
         $("#imgArrows").attr('title', 'Show');
         isHidden = false; /*set it to false*/
  }
});

   $('#imgArrows').hover(function () {
      /*here you check value of isHidden variable*/
      if(isHidden){ 
          $("#imgArrows").attr('title', 'Show');
     }
   },function(){
       $("#imgArrows").attr('title', 'Hide');
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It works on Opera browser (weirdly not showing arrow images though), but not working on the IE.(image arrows appear fine). @black123

Comment: Showing/not showing images in different browsers may be related to css you used. Since jQuery is tested library, I don't think it is an issue of jQuery.